# Background from ul element covers whole page

Tags: css, html, user-interface

Instead of my background only acting as a background for the 4 different types of pottery in the ul element, the red background covers my name and navigation bar. Why is it doing this? I have tried to make everything relative positioning but doesnt seem to make a difference. Why is the ul element not following the flow of the document, it should sit below my name and navigation.

Please advise, see example here: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4GUkU/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting your problem correct then here is the solution

check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GUkU/2/

Note: Please let me know if am lagging here so i can change as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Browers have a difficult time with heights of floated DIVs.  The easiest thing to do is to put:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

The red color everywhere is due to

```
#featured {
  ...
  background-color:Red;
  ...
}
```

And the UL displays below "The Pottery Club" and the nav links for me (in Chrome). Which browser are you using?

Comment: @ Alexander Pavlov I know that it is set to red, however it shouldnt be covering the ul element, logo and nav, it should be acting as a background for for the ul element. I'm using Firefox since i can use firebug in it. All i can see is a big red square; however in chrome i see 2 links which it should be a horizontal list of 4.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, semantically you do not need to use  and

in a  tag.  tags are already interpreted vertically, unless you choose otherwise with CSS.

You could rewrite your navigation menu like so:

```
<nav id="nav-main">
    <a title="Book Class" href="">Book Class</a>
    <a title="Plan your visit" href="/visiting">Plan your visit</a>
    <a title="Contact us" href="/visiting">Contact us</a>
</nav>
```

If you keep the  and

in your , a blind person's reader would read to him/her: "navigation, unordered list, list-item..." which does not make very much sense.

Comment: My list is suppose to be horizontal with a red background. However, will take the bling person's issue into consideration